# A problem occurred configuring root project

Tags: android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'Android-Screen-to-Face-Distance-Measurement-master'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency com.android.tools.build:gradle because no repositories are defined.
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36ms
12:12:17: Task execution finished 'dependencies --stacktrace'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801157/how-to-fix-gradle-build-error-a-problem-occurred-configuring-root-project

Comment: Please post `build.gradle` of App and Project